# How to validate fields using the functions .each() and ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, magento

So. I am trying create a fields validation using ajax. I have created the class "validate-field" on the fields where is a necessary a validation.

One Field is email_addres and another is taxvat. On my controller I just created thea action  "validate" and then I am trying get the Field ID and Field Value.

Follow the codes below:

-the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery(".continuar").on("click", function(){

            url = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('awmajax/ajax/validar')?>";

            jQuery(".required-entry").each(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).val() == ""){
                    jQuery(this).addClass("validation-failed");
                }
                else {
                    jQuery(this).removeClass("validation-failed");
                }
            });


            jQuery(".validate-field").each(function(){
                fieldName = jQuery(this).attr('id');
                fieldValue = jQuery(this).val();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: ({
                        field : fieldName,
                        value : fieldValue

                    }),
                    success: function(result){


                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

and the php:

```
public function validarAction(){

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();    

        if($params['field'] == 'taxvat'){
            $taxvat = $params['value'];
            $validacao = Mage::helper('awm_awmajax')->validaCPF($taxvat);
            if($validacao == false){
                $resultTaxvat = array(
                    "response"  => "Taxvat is not valid",
                    "field"     => $params['field']
                );

            }
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($resultTaxvat));
        }

        if($params['field'] = 'email_address'){

            $emailAddress = $params['value'];
            $validacaoEmail = Mage::helper('awm_awmajax')->checkEmailExists($emailAddress);

            $resultEmail = array(
                "response"  => $validacaoEmail, //Type a valid Email
                "field"     => $params['field']
            );
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($resultEmail));
        }

    }
```

What is the problem:

I get always just the email response on the second "If".
Any help is welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

your second IF statement is passing a value and not comparing... I think you were supposed to write `if ($params['field'] === 'email_address')`

regarding your issue, try this:

```
public function validarAction()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $error = false;
    $errors = [];

    if ($params['field'] == 'taxvat') {
        $taxvat = $params['value'];
        $validacao = Mage::helper('awm_awmajax')->validaCPF($taxvat);

        if (!$validacao) {
            $error = true;
            $errors[] = [
                'field' => $params['field'],
                'message' => 'Taxvat is not valid',
            ];
        }
    }

    if ($params['field'] === 'email_address') {
        $emailAddress = $params['value'];
        $validacaoEmail = Mage::helper('awm_awmajax')->checkEmailExists($emailAddress);

        if (!$$validacaoEmail) {
            $error = true;
            $errors[] = [
                'field' => $params['field'],
                'message' => 'Type a valid Email',
            ];
        }
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode([
        'error' => $error,
        'errors' => $errors
    ]));
}
```

...tyr to use a loop construct to refactor this. as this may result in a lot of IF statements if you are going to validate a lot of fields.

EDIT:
Changed `$result` to `$errors` and the JSON index `status` to `error`. It would be easier to iterate with the updated code on your JS.

Comment: Hey Ubuntux. 
Thanks to reply and help me.
Yeah. I was thinking about that. For now it is not many fields but  we will increase that with more information details.

I will try that.
Cheers


ps: I thnking I have deleted the compare signal when I pasted here.

Comment: I made a few modifications as well.